# Boundingbox with title?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Sir I have a binary image with four objects and a matrix(4x4).I want to use the matrix for the image. Suppose in the first column of the matrix , the position of the highest element is 3 and the first column corresponds to first object. So I want to give that object a boundingbox with title 'Type3 OBJECT'. Similarly for the second object , in the second column the position of the highest element is 1. So I want to add boundingbox to that object with title 'Type1 OBJECT'. Sir how can I make it using regionprops. Should I use it with for loop?
Thanks. This is the image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nMWQ.png)

Comment: Sir, we don't understand what you're asking us.  Can you please explain more sir?  Also, which "sir" are you referring to?  There is more than one "sir" here.

Comment: Of course m referring my prblm to you Sir Rayyeng. Ok I am explaining simpl wy. Sir, in matlab is it possible to draw a boundingbox in particular seleted object. Suppose in a image with 5 objects is it possible to draw a bbox in the second object by using bwlabel and regionprops.

Comment: Can you give me some idea?

Comment: What do neural networks have to do with your question? I'll write an answer, but I'm just curious as to your tag.

Comment: Actually I am trying to relate an neural network output matrix with a  image. From the output matrix I want to show object type with bbox in the  image. I am working in a problem related to defect detection.

Comment: Rayryeng .......can u give some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir, you can get the bounding boxes from the `regionprops` function, and then use the `insertObjectAnnotation` function from the Computer Vision System Toolbox to draw the boxes with annotations into the image.